# PHP String(which contain array of object) to Array conversion

Tags: php, arrays, json

Suppose I have a string (which contain array of objects):

```
$string = "[{'test':'1', 'anothertest':'2'}, {'test':'3', 'anothertest':'4'}]";
```

My goals is to get the output to look like this when I `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test] => 1
            [anothertest] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test] => 3
            [anothertest] => 4
        )

)
```

I tried to `json_decode($string)` but it returned `NULL`

Also tried my own workaround which is kinda solved the problem,

```
$string = "[{'test':'1', 'anothertest':'2'}, {'test':'3', 'anothertest':'4'}]";
$string = substr($string, 1, -1);
$string = str_replace("'","\"", $string);
$string = str_replace("},","}VerySpecialSeparator", $string);
$arrayOfString = explode("VerySpecialSeparator",$string);
$results = [];
    
foreach($arrayOfString as $string) {
    $results[] = json_decode($string, true);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
die;
```

But is there any other ways to solve this?

Comment: this is not valid json in your string. did you try `unserialize`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Unserialize the $string will cause an error. This is the error: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 65 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your given data, if quotes will be corrected, then you will get your desired output, so get it done like below:

```
<?php

$string = "[{'test':'1', 'anothertest':'2'}, {'test':'3', 'anothertest':'4'}]";
$string = str_replace("'",'"', $string);
print_r(json_decode($string,true));
```

https://3v4l.org/PDI7O

Comment: Thank you very much haha, didn't realize i made such a small mistake

Comment: No, problem, happens to all at the beginning